# Restheart query for an nested array subdocument

Tags: arrays, mongodb, subdocument, restheart

I m working with mongodb and restheart.

In my nosql db i have a unique document with this structure:

```
{
"_id": "docID",
"users": [
            {
             "userID": "12",                 
             "elements": [
                         {
                          "elementID": "1492446877599",
                          "events": [
                                     {
                                      "event1": "one"
                                     },   
                                     {                                       
                                      "event2": "two",
                                      }
                                     ]
                           }
               },
              {
             "userID": "11",                 
             "elements": [
                         {
                          "elementID": "14924",
                          "events": [
                                     {
                                      "event1": "one"
                                     },   
                                     {                                       
                                      "event2": "two",
                                      }
                                     ]
                           }
               }  

              ]  
}
```

how can i build an url-query in order to get the user with id 11?

Using mongo shell it should be something like this one:

```
db.getCollection('collection').find({},{'users':{'$elemMatch':{'userID':'12'}}}).pretty()
```

I cannot find anything similar on restheart.

Could someone help me?

Using this

```
http://myHost:port/documents/docID?filter={%27users%27:{%27$elemMatch%27:{%27userID%27:%2712%27}}}
```

restheart returns me all the documents: userID 11 and 12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your request is against a document resource, i.e. the URL is `http://myHost:port/documents/docID`

The *filter* query parameter applies for collection requests, i.e. URLs such as `http://myHost:port/documents`

In any case you need to projection (the *keys* query parameter) to limit the returned properties.

You should achieve it with the following request (I haven't tried it) using the [$elementMatch projection operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/):

`http://myHost:port/documents?keys={"users":{"$elemMatch":{"userID":"12"}}}`